# Some animated Adsense ads prevent the rest of the page from functioning

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, performance

I've had this problem for the best part of 3 months now.
Since doing a major update in March, some recurring ads make the site unusable.
I've requested help on this issue multiple times but nobody has yet suggested a solution.

I know it's the ads causing this lag, if I delete them in Chrome's developer tools or isolate them, it's very clear that they're the culprit.
You'll notice some ads follow the page. I've tried disabling this script (and every other running script) and this doesn't help.
Also, I've been told it's Flash's fault (my site mostly features Flash games) but it clearly isn't, some pages don't have any Flash objects and yet the problem still persists just as badly.

I just don't understand it, Google have burdened me with some horrible ads (at least on my end) that are basically malicious in that they destroy functionality of any page they display on.
I am mystified why I can't find other people with a similar problem, as some specific recurring ads are so badly broken that a single one can ruin performance for the entire page.

With the Google Publisher Toolbar I've block and reported the bad ones, but they come back within a week or so.
Some ads spew out hundreds of warnings and errors, some ads are just horribly inefficient animated canvases with loads of moving elements.

What else can I do to prevent/fix these ads besides using a different ad service?

Comment: I have not had your problem with Google's ads, however, I have seen on other networks, ads, especially video ads, that just plain chew up a CPU. Some sites load so much junk, and not just ads, that they take minutes to finish downloading. Then there is the pop-ups and the refreshing of ads and content using javascript. The whole thing is annoying as hell. I am not sure what your specific problem is. As for myself, I have not seen Google serve bad ads, but I would not be surprised if some are slower. As for size and speed, that can be measured (I assume) using Chrome.